# php java how do I create a popup login form which will delay for 2sec

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, popup

I want to create a popup form after diplaying the search results. As I only know very little about javascript, how do I create a popup form which will delay for 2sec after showing the results? Please help me

**current using form**

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <table class="form_font" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td class="title" colspan="2">Log in<br /> <hr style="width:100%; background-color:#000000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><?php echo $error_MSG;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Don't have an account? <span class="form_font2"><a href="rates_signup.php">Create one.</a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Email Address:</td><td><input style="width:180px" type="text" name="email"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Password:</td><td><input style="width:180px" type="password" name="password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td align="right">
      <table class="form_font">
      <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="remember"/></td><td>Remember me (10days)</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td align="right"><input type="submit" class="submitStyle" name="login" value="login"/><input type="submit" name="email_newpass" value="E-mail new password"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

**How do I change it to this:**
[image]

Comment: You may use [jquery](http://jquery.com), which contains utilities for delay and gradual display.

Comment: See this implementation and demo. Easy to use and nice explanation of howto's. Also, flexible configuration. http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var displayPopUp = function() {
    setTimeout( function() {
      //This is the part where you display your pop-up
    }, 2000 );
  };
  document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[ 0 ].addEventListener( 'load', displayPopUp );
</script>
```

What this script does is that it creates a function `displayPopUp` which gets called after the `body` is loaded. The function creates a timer that will execute after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

What I see in your image seem a modal window.
see: [Modal Form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) of jquery-UI extension.

I create an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan/6Cfu2/) on jsfiddle, it works but has some CSS issue (may be Jsfiddle, me be my code :)

The trigger of modal window after 2 second is:

```
 setTimeout( function() {
  $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
}, 2000 );
```

as suggest by @Interfector